# Overlaying DIVs in the center of the browser window

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am using  jQuery animation to fade to images and for this to work the two images are in a DIV inside of a DIV to make it look like one is fading into the other, and one is positioned on top of the other. It works, all I want to do is move it to the center of my page and can't seem to make it work. Here is the HTML and CSS. I tried modifying the margins, the top and left positioning and such, but nothing has worked successfully. Thanks for any feedback.

EDIT: What I want is one DIV directly on top of the other. They are both filled with the same image, except one has a glow around it that I created in an editing software. When the page loads, the jQuery triggers the first div, .fade, to fade out, and allow to other div, .inside, to fade in, creating an animation that makes it look as if one image is slowly changing into another. This already happens automatically and works perfectly. I just would like the images to be centered directly in the middle of the browser window as it happens instead of it's automatic placement on the left.

CSS

```
    .container
    {
        position:relative;
    }
    .fade
    {
        position: absolute;
        z-index:1;
        top:0;
        left:0;
    }
    .inside
    {
        position: absolute;
        display: none;
        z-index:2;
        top:0;
        left:0;
    }
```

HTML

```
    <div class="container">
            <div class="fade">
                <img src="namelarge.png" />
                    <div class="inside">
                        <img src="nameglow.png" />
                    </div>
            </div>
        </div>
```

EDIT: Here is my jQuery

```
$(window).load(function () {
setTimeout(function () {
    $('div.fade > div') . fadeIn(3000) // 3 second fade in
}, 2000) // after 2 seconds. })
```

Comment: Where is said jQuery?

Comment: <script>
    $(window).load(function () {
    setTimeout(function () {
        $('div.fade > div') . fadeIn(3000) // 3 second fade in
    }, 2000) // after 2 seconds.
})
    </script>

Comment: Does the image have a fixed size?

Answer (score 0):

I'll assume you're trying to center the .fade div within the .container div.

take out the top and left properties from the .fade css, define the width property, and add:

```
margin: 0 auto;
```

this should center it horizontally.

Comment: No avail: still in the same spot, on the left of the page and now the DIVs are no longer one on top of the other. I'm trying to paste in the new css but this comment option says it is too many characters and I don't see another way to reply haha.

Comment: @user2396038 can you please post a fiddle?

Answer (score 0):

if you want to center the `.fade` div try:

```
.fade {
position:relative;
width:50px;
z-index:1;
margin:auto;
}
.inside {
position: absolute;
display: none;
z-index:2;
top:0;
left:0;
}
```

Check here: [jsfiddle.net/TcfBH/](http://jsfiddle.net/TcfBH/2/) (v2)

Comment: Moved it to the far right of my page and took the top DIV off of the bottom DIV. One has to overlay the other for the animation to work properly.

Comment: ok, just updated my answer. Added `position:relative` to `.fade` and `position:absolute` to `.inside`

Comment: My DIVs are back one over the other like I want, but it's still not in the center :/ It's over to the right of my page as if it is right aligned. I can't figure out why it would do that.

Comment: Did you check the jsfiddle? does it look good there? Please share a live link so we can help more.

Comment: It was the 50 on the width that was causing the problem - didn't occur to me to change it for my image. It works great now. Thanks for the help! :)